# MySQL Image Storing

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob

I want to create an online RPG game..! I searched for tutorials on net about storing images in MySQL.. but all where simply different..from what I actually needed!

I don't want to "Upload" any images! My server will be having all images..for example.. Pokemons!!.. already stored in my server! I just need the user to select one pokemon and store the related data in his account!

[image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2nhgu4x.jpg]

Above is the example what I actually want. There's no Upload Image etc etc... All data and images would be already stored and users only have to fetch them in their account!

I don't want the exact code... but if you can explain me how is it done..or give any similar tutorial I will be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to store the images in your database: just store it somewhere in your server, and in your database just store *the path to this image* in a table like `POKEMON(id, name, path_to_image)`.

Then in your code, use the path stored in the database to get the link to the image. And also, when a user will capture a Pokemon, you'll need a table like `CAPTURE(user_id, pokemon_id)`.

Comment: Yaa exactly what I wanted.! 
But do you have a good tutorial about what u just explained! It would help me alot!

Comment: I missed one thing! A user should have many pokemons...in his account! How can i code this mechanism.. Its not possible to keep inserting every Pokemon ID in the tables... everytime is catches a new one :\

Comment: So you will have 2 pokemons table: the first one describe all the possible Pokemons: `POKEMON(id, name, path_to_image)` so typically you will have only 151 entries in that table (one for Pikachu, one for Mew etc.); and a second one with the **instances** of the captured pokemons: `CAPTURED_POKEMONS(user_id, pokemon_id, capture_date, given_name, ...)` etc. 
This way, a given user can have 3 differents Pikachu, and only have one reference to Pikachu's image in your DB.

Comment: So when a User catches a pokemon! Change will be made at the 2nd table..means table containing instances of the captured pokemon! (y) 
But when a user captures a pokemon,... which column of the table will be updated and how???

Comment: This table will not be __updated__ but __inserted__: when user #1 will capture pokemon #23 and rename it 'Roberto', you will have :
`INSERT INTO CAPTURED_POKEMONS VALUES (1, 23, now(), 'Roberto');`

Comment: `POKEMON(23, "Mew", "../../mew.png");`

`CAPTURED_POKEMONS VALUES (1, 23, now(), 'Roberto');`
Take a look at [this database relationships tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) for more informations.

Comment: Cool! I got it!! thnks alot! 
If I have any prob futher.. i will surely contact you (y) thnks once again

Comment: Hey Deigo! 
It means that if userid #7 is having 20 pokemons, there would be 20 rows or say entries, of id #7 in single table(CAPTURED_POKEMONS)??

Comment: Yes you will have 20 entries if he has 20 pokemons. The primary key of this table should be (user_id, pokemon_id, capture_date)

Comment: hey Deigo! If one user is having 5 Mewtwo's but every mewtwo is having diff levels! Then how can the coding work??
I mean the database table will store userid #50 haves #pkmnid 150(mewtwo)... This would be repeated 5 times..as user has 5 mewtwos... ! I think this would make prob during fetching correct mewtwo :\

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you need, but if you just want users to be able to add an image or images to their account, perhaps as avatars then you just need a column in your table for the filename(s) or URL(s) to the image.

You could store the image itself as a binary but that is usually unnecessary and ultimately creates table bloat - especially if two (or more) users could have the same image.

Comment: No! I dont want it like that...! In RPG's , Theres a user account! And user has to catch(add) pokemons to their accounts.
So there is no limit for catching or adding pokemons to their accounts. Also according to pokemons their related date like its name,level,powers,type etc etc... also should be store in the database, which is predefined!                           http://oi62.tinypic.com/4j5gsn.jpg